# Запрос WHERE ... IN используя prepare PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, preparedstatement

Напоролся на засаду... Не могу понять, как правильно построить запрос (WHERE IN) в PDO.
При обычном построении запроса я бы написал примерно так:

```
$params = array(1, 3, 7);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (".implode(',',$params).")");
// и т.д.
// В итоге - получаем три записи
```

Наивно надеялся, что в PDO не надо будет ломать голову. Пробовал написать так:

```
$params = array(1, 3, 7);
$e = $db-> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (?)");
$e -> execute((array(implode(',',$params))));
$e -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Итог - только одна запись
```

Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, то прошу подсказать в какую сторону рыть надо.

P.S. Без prepare и плейсхолдеров, естественно, что работает нормально, но это не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)](/users/4058/deonis) - query строку можно подготовить немного красивее.

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (" .
substr( str_repeat( '?, ', count($params) ), 0, -1 ) .
')';
```

А так да, иначе никак.

С другой стороны ничего страшного не вижу в функции вида

```
function arrayQuery( $query, $params ) {
  return str_replace('array(?)',substr(str_repeat('?,', count($params)),0,-1),$query);
}

$query = arrayQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (array(?))", array(1,2,3));
```

Естественно идею можно развить и реализовать массивы в полной степени

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню - никак. В Postgres можно было бы сделать что-то вроде:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ANY(?::int[])
```

И затем передавать параметр как `'{'.implode(',',$params).'}'`. Но в MySQL нет массивов, по этому это не будет работать.

Comment: Как-то не вериться, что не совсем стандартные запросы не учтены в PDO. Инет кишит статьями, написанными, как под копирку, где показаны примеры с простейшими запросами, но с не стандартными - пока найти не удалось. Думаю, что способ должен быть... просто пока не нащупал.

Comment: Способ один - не использовать в этом случае placeholder.

Comment: Ну, один способ всё же нашел. Может он слегка индуский, но вроде как работает. Суть проста - подготовить строку запроса с определенным кол-вом плейсхолдеров в зависимости от размера массива. Пока не доработал до ума, но что-то в этом роде:

    $params = array(1, 3, 7);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($params);$i++){
     $query .= "?,"; 
    }
    $query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-1);
    $query .= ")";
    $e = $db-> prepare($query);
    $e -> execute($params);

Правильно или нет, но работает

Comment: @Deonis, да, вариант. Только смысл в prepared statements несколько теряется, поскольку перед каждым запросом все равно придется prepare вызывать.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, так или иначе, но без костыля тут, увы, не обойтись. В официальной документации дали ясно понять:   > You cannot bind multiple values to a single parameter; for example, you cannot bind two values to a single named parameter in an IN() clause.[Пруфлинк](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php). Переживём, но осадок остался ;)

Answer (score 0):

Worked!

```
$e = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (".implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?')).")");

$e->execute($params);
```

Comment: Благодарю, уважаемый, но если вы обратите внимание на даты этого обсуждения, то станет очевидным, что этот вопрос уже очень давно не актуален. И кстати, строковые функции работают быстрее, поэтому вариант @Zowie все равно выигрывает ;)

Comment: Причем тут дата обсуждения? Это не приватное обсуждение. Эта тема открыта для поисковиков, а значит сюда будут переходить люди с поисковика независимо от вашей даты. Так что ответ будет актуальным до тех пор, пока ссылка находится в результатах ранжирования.

Comment: И кстати первый пример от Zowie не рабочий. Там надо либо заменить -1 на -2, либо убрать пробел из повторяемой строки '?, '

Comment: Да отвечайте на здоровье )) Никто вам это и не запретит. Я же, как автор вопроса, просто отреагировал на новое сообщение, что тоже не воспрещается делать ;) А функция Zowie рабочая на все 100% без единой правки.

Comment: Причем тут функция? Я же написал ПЕРВЫЙ пример, а не функция.